# NextCord and WavelinkCord

Tags: nextcord

I have this code below to a music discord bot in python, but i've got some errors

```py
    import nextcord
    from nextcord.ext import commands
    from nextcord.shard import EventItem
    import os
    import wavelinkcord as wavelink
    
    BOT_TOKEN = 'Token'
    
    # the prefix is not used in this example
    intents = nextcord.Intents.all()
    client  = nextcord.Client(intents=intents)
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)
    
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready(): # evento para quando o bot estiver pronto
        print(f'Loggado como {bot.user.name} - {bot.user.id}') # imprime no console o nome e o id do bot
        print(f'Versão: {nextcord.__version__}') # imprime no console a versão da lib
        print('Bot operando com sucesso...!') # imprime no console que o bot está operando com sucesso
        bot.loop.create_task(on_node()) # cria uma task para o evento on_node
    
    async def on_node(): # evento para quando o node estiver pronto
        node: wavelink.Node = wavelink.Node(uri="http://localhost:2333", password="notpass") # cria um node
        await wavelink.NodePool.connect(client=bot, nodes=[node]) # conecta o node ao bot
        wavelink.Player.autoplay = True # ativa o autoplay
    
    @bot.slash_command(guild_ids=[])
    async def play(interaction: nextcord.Interaction, search: str): # comando para tocar uma música
        query = await wavelink.YouTubeTrack.search(search) # pesquisa a música
        destination = interaction.user.voice.channel # pega o canal de voz do autor da interação
    
        if not interaction.guild.voice_client:
            vc: wavelink.Player = await destination.connect(cls=wavelink.Player) # conecta ao canal de voz
        else:
            vc: wavelink.Player = interaction.guild.voice_client
        if vc.queue.is_empty and not vc.is_playing: # verifica se a fila está vazia e se não está tocando
            await vc.play(query) # toca a música
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"Tocando agora {vc.current.title}!") # envia uma mensagem de confirmação
        else:
            await vc.queue.put_wait(query) # adiciona a música à fila
            await interaction.response.send_message("Música adicionada à fila!") # envia uma mensagem de confirmação
    
    @bot.slash_command(guild_ids=[])
    async def skip(interaction: nextcord.Interaction): # comando para pular uma música
        vc: wavelink.Player = interaction.guild.voice_client # pega o voice client do servidor
        await vc.stop() # para a música
        await interaction.response.send_message("Música pulada!") # envia uma mensagem de confirmação
    
    @bot.slash_command(guild_ids=[])
    async def pause(interaction: nextcord.Interaction): # comando para pausar uma música
        vc: wavelink.Player = interaction.guild.voice_client # pega o voice client do servidor
    
        if vc.is_playing():
            await vc.pause() # pausa a música
            await interaction.response.send_message("Música pausada!") # envia uma mensagem de confirmação
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Não estou tocando nada!")
    
    @bot.slash_command(guild_ids=[])
    async def resume(interaction: nextcord.Interaction): # comando para pausar uma música
        vc: wavelink.Player = interaction.guild.voice_client # pega o voice client do servidor
    
        if vc.is_playing():
            await interaction.response.send_message("Estou tocando uma música já") # envia uma mensagem de confirmação
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Música tocando!") # envia uma mensagem de confirmação
            await vc.resume()
    
    @bot.slash_command(guild_ids=[])
    async def disconnect(interaction: nextcord.Interaction): # comando para parar uma música
        vc: wavelink.Player = interaction.guild.voice_client # pega o voice client do servidor
        await vc.disconnect() # desconecta do canal de voz
        await interaction.response.send_message("Desconectado do canal de voz!") # envia uma mensagem de confirmação
    
    @bot.slash_command(guild_ids=[])
    async def queue(interaction: nextcord.Interaction): # comando para ver a fila
        vc: wavelink.Player = interaction.guild.voice_client # pega o voice client do servidor
        if not vc.queue.is_empty:
            song_counter = 0
            songs = []
            queue = vc.queue.copy()
            embed = nextcord.Embed(title="Fila de músicas", color=nextcord.Color.blurple())
    
            for song in queue:
                song_counter += 1
                songs.append(song)
                embed.add_field(name=f"[{song_counter}] - {song.title}", value=f"Duração: {song.duration}", inline=False)
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Não há músicas na fila!")
    
    bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

I have this file to configure the lavalink too:

```
aplication.yml
```

```yaml
    server: # REST and WS server
      port: 2333 # you can change this if u want
      address: 0.0.0.0 #you can change this too
    spring:
      main:
        banner-mode: log
    lavalink:
      server:
        password: "notpass"
        sources:
          youtube: true
          bandcamp: false
          soundcloud: false
          twitch: false
          vimeo: false
          mixer: false
          http: false
          local: true
        bufferDurationMs: 400
        youtubePlaylistLoadLimit: 6 # Number of pages at 100 each
        gc-warnings: true
    
    metrics:
      prometheus:
        enabled: false
        endpoint: /metrics
    
    sentry:
      dsn: ""
    #  tags:
    #    some_key: some_value
    #    another_key: another_value
    
    logging:
      file:
        max-history: 30
        max-size: 100MB
      path: ./logs/
    
      level:
        root: INFO
        lavalink: INFO
```

Error: An error occurred connecting to node: "Node: id="O2WrMwvqEFN1", uri="http://localhost:2333", status=NodeStatus.CONNECTING". Cannot connect to host localhost:2333 ssl:default [O computador remoto recusou a conexão de rede]
wavelinkcord 2.0 was unable to connect, retrying connection in: "1.9059734030955238" seconds.

I have this code below to a music discord bot in python, but i've got some errors

```py
    import nextcord
    from nextcord.ext import commands
    from nextcord.shard import EventItem
    import os
    import wavelinkcord as wavelink
    
    BOT_TOKEN = 'Token'
    
    # the prefix is not used in this example
    intents = nextcord.Intents.all()
    client  = nextcord.Client(intents=intents)
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)
    
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready(): # evento para quando o bot estiver pronto
        print(f'Loggado como {bot.user.name} - {bot.user.id}') # imprime no console o nome e o id do bot
        print(f'Versão: {nextcord.__version__}') # imprime no console a versão da lib
        print('Bot operando com sucesso...!') # imprime no console que o bot está operando com sucesso
        bot.loop.create_task(on_node()) # cria uma task para o evento on_node
    
    async def on_node(): # evento para quando o node estiver pronto
        node: wavelink.Node = wavelink.Node(uri="http://localhost:2333", password="notpass") # cria um node
        await wavelink.NodePool.connect(client=bot, nodes=[node]) # conecta o node ao bot
        wavelink.Player.autoplay = True # ativa o autoplay
    
    @bot.slash_command(guild_ids=[])
    async def play(interaction: nextcord.Interaction, search: str): # comando para tocar uma música
        query = await wavelink.YouTubeTrack.search(search) # pesquisa a música
        destination = interaction.user.voice.channel # pega o canal de voz do autor da interação
    
        if not interaction.guild.voice_client:
            vc: wavelink.Player = await destination.connect(cls=wavelink.Player) # conecta ao canal de voz
        else:
            vc: wavelink.Player = interaction.guild.voice_client
        if vc.queue.is_empty and not vc.is_playing: # verifica se a fila está vazia e se não está tocando
            await vc.play(query) # toca a música
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"Tocando agora {vc.current.title}!") # envia uma mensagem de confirmação
        else:
            await vc.queue.put_wait(query) # adiciona a música à fila
            await interaction.response.send_message("Música adicionada à fila!") # envia uma mensagem de confirmação
    
    @bot.slash_command(guild_ids=[])
    async def skip(interaction: nextcord.Interaction): # comando para pular uma música
        vc: wavelink.Player = interaction.guild.voice_client # pega o voice client do servidor
        await vc.stop() # para a música
        await interaction.response.send_message("Música pulada!") # envia uma mensagem de confirmação
    
    @bot.slash_command(guild_ids=[])
    async def pause(interaction: nextcord.Interaction): # comando para pausar uma música
        vc: wavelink.Player = interaction.guild.voice_client # pega o voice client do servidor
    
        if vc.is_playing():
            await vc.pause() # pausa a música
            await interaction.response.send_message("Música pausada!") # envia uma mensagem de confirmação
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Não estou tocando nada!")
    
    @bot.slash_command(guild_ids=[])
    async def resume(interaction: nextcord.Interaction): # comando para pausar uma música
        vc: wavelink.Player = interaction.guild.voice_client # pega o voice client do servidor
    
        if vc.is_playing():
            await interaction.response.send_message("Estou tocando uma música já") # envia uma mensagem de confirmação
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Música tocando!") # envia uma mensagem de confirmação
            await vc.resume()
    
    @bot.slash_command(guild_ids=[])
    async def disconnect(interaction: nextcord.Interaction): # comando para parar uma música
        vc: wavelink.Player = interaction.guild.voice_client # pega o voice client do servidor
        await vc.disconnect() # desconecta do canal de voz
        await interaction.response.send_message("Desconectado do canal de voz!") # envia uma mensagem de confirmação
    
    @bot.slash_command(guild_ids=[])
    async def queue(interaction: nextcord.Interaction): # comando para ver a fila
        vc: wavelink.Player = interaction.guild.voice_client # pega o voice client do servidor
        if not vc.queue.is_empty:
            song_counter = 0
            songs = []
            queue = vc.queue.copy()
            embed = nextcord.Embed(title="Fila de músicas", color=nextcord.Color.blurple())
    
            for song in queue:
                song_counter += 1
                songs.append(song)
                embed.add_field(name=f"[{song_counter}] - {song.title}", value=f"Duração: {song.duration}", inline=False)
            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Não há músicas na fila!")
    
    bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

I have this file to configure the lavalink too:

```
aplication.yml
```

```yaml
    server: # REST and WS server
      port: 2333 # you can change this if u want
      address: 0.0.0.0 #you can change this too
    spring:
      main:
        banner-mode: log
    lavalink:
      server:
        password: "notpass"
        sources:
          youtube: true
          bandcamp: false
          soundcloud: false
          twitch: false
          vimeo: false
          mixer: false
          http: false
          local: true
        bufferDurationMs: 400
        youtubePlaylistLoadLimit: 6 # Number of pages at 100 each
        gc-warnings: true
    
    metrics:
      prometheus:
        enabled: false
        endpoint: /metrics
    
    sentry:
      dsn: ""
    #  tags:
    #    some_key: some_value
    #    another_key: another_value
    
    logging:
      file:
        max-history: 30
        max-size: 100MB
      path: ./logs/
    
      level:
        root: INFO
        lavalink: INFO
```

Error: An error occurred connecting to node: "Node: id="O2WrMwvqEFN1", uri="http://localhost:2333", status=NodeStatus.CONNECTING". Cannot connect to host localhost:2333 ssl:default [O computador remoto recusou a conexão de rede]
wavelinkcord 2.0 was unable to connect, retrying connection in: "1.9059734030955238" seconds.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
node: wavelink.Node = wavelink.Node(uri="http://localhost:2333", password="notpass")
```

to

```
node: wl.Node = wl.Node(uri = 'https://lavalink.teramont.net:443', password='eHKuFcz67k4lBS64', secure=True)
```